# NetLogo: getting randomly chosen position of a repeated value in a list

Tags: netlogo

If I have the following: `set list [8 1 0 3 4 2 0 1 2 4 25 0 3 3]`. I would like to find a way to get, for example, a random item position for zero (2, 6 or 11) or for three (3, 12 or 13).

I have tried with:

```
let i (position (one-of list = 0) list )
print i
```

However, that only returns a boolean `i`. I know I could use `position 0 list`, but that gives priority to the first position (2, in the case of zero) while I would like it to randomly chosen from all values equal to zero on the list. I thought of using a `while[]`, but I was wondering if there is a faster and simpler way.

Comment: NetLogo does not have an individual procedure that lets you retrive all the positions of the item you are looking for in a list. You have to make it on your own, i.e. using `while` as you said or an equivalent strategy.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo, I supposed there was no procedure to do something like that, just wanted to make sure. I could manage to do something with a ```while``` to get done, finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you are working with lists, it is a good idea to familiarise yourself with [anonymous procedures](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures) and some related primitives like [`map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) and [`filter`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter).

I wrote a quick procedure, called `positions` that should be able to take care of this. First I create a list containing all the possible indexes: `index-list`.
Next, I use `map` to simultaneously go through the `input-list` and the `index-list`. It uses `ifelse-value` to check for each item of the `input-list` whether or not it corresponds to the `input-item` that you wanted to check it against. If they correspond, it returns the position of that item in the input-list. Otherwise it returns FALSE.
The final step is to `filter` out all the FALSE responses so that you are left with a list containing only the positions of your `input-item` in the `input-list`.

```
to-report positions [ input-item input-list ]
  
  let index-list range length input-list
  
  let position-list (map [ [list-item index] -> ifelse-value input-item = list-item [index][FALSE] ] input-list index-list)
  
  report filter [index -> index != FALSE] position-list

end
```

Testing this gives `[2 6 11]` as a result, which corresponds with what you would expect

```
to test

  let my-list [8 1 0 3 4 2 0 1 2 4 25 0 3 3]
  
  show positions 0 my-list ;[2 6 11]
  
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LeirsW, that helped me a lot. I am still getting familiarized with anonymous procedures and they feel a bit difficult to think for me. Any advice to improve with using them?

Comment: @Pol The general advice is to just use them. I mainly learned to use them by trying to answer other people's answers here on stackoverflow, and by trying to solve a few generic coding challenges (https://adventofcode.com/) using Netlogo. These challenges often worked with lists.